# Why are wide throw hinges so expensive relative to normal ones?

Tags: shed, hinges

For some reason, neither Home Depot or Lowe's sell wide-throw hinges. They sell regular hinges of all sizes, but not wide-throw hinges. For reference, a wide-throw hinge is one where the hinge's expanded width is longer than its height.

The only sellers I've found for wide-throw hinges are Amazon, HardwareSource, and Hinge Outlet (which also has an Amazon store).

On Hinge Outlet's Amazon store, you can see a [4.5 x 6-inch wide-throw hinge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PJXHP32) being sold for basically $70.

A regular [4.5-inch tall hinge at Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Global-Door-Controls-4-5-in-x-4-5-in-Brushed-Chrome-Mortise-Non-Removable-Pin-Squared-Hinge-Set-of-3-CP4545BBNRP-26D-3/203384277) goes for about $15.

Why the large price gap? Why do such few stores sell wide-throw hinges?
Is HardwareSource a trustworthy online seller? I tried purchasing a hinge there, and my bank declined the transaction BOTH times.

I am hoping to use the hinge for a shed door.

Comment: This question is purely speculative. The answer usually has to do with sales volume. What problem are you trying to solve, besides budget?

Comment: The expensive hinge is "ball bearing." Sounds like they're using a sealed bearings instead of the typical greasy pin. The eccentricity of the forces in a similarly detailed wide throw hinge will require thicker plates in addition to the larger area, where that implies more cost.

Comment: If these hinges will be surface mounted instead of edge mounted, then consider "gate" or "barn door" hinges.

Comment: The answer is "economies of scale". More commonly used stuff is stocked more places, sold more comparatively, doesn't need to recoup as much design/tooling investment. Basic economics.

Comment: Just to properly compare prices, the wide-throw hinge price is for 2 so its $35 each  The regular hinge price is for 3, so its $5 each.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the supply and demand influence on price (which is significant), this hinge is significantly different than a normal 4 1/2" door hinge:

[image]